# How can i use indian rupee symbol in sublime text 2 editor in ubuntu 12.04LTS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, sublimetext, money-rails

I want to use indian rupee symbol in my sublime text editor 2. I have googled for more than 4 hours but i didn't find a solution. I have download the font and installed it. Now its working only for my LibreOfficeWriter. I am following [gem 'money-rails'](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) in my application. I want to use that symbol in my money.rb to set the default currency value to INR. Any helps welcome.

Comment: I dont get it, why dont you just copy the rupee character ₹ from wikipedia or something? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupee

Comment: @joni: For each and everytime i want to use that symbol means i have to copy it from some where as you said copy from wiki so on. I want some permanent solution. Thats it... :)